# Visual Studio, how to auto insert parameter name labels?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was watching a video on ASP.NET Core in VS 2022 and noticed when the host hit semi-colon at end of a line he was typing, VS would insert the names of parameters in method calls. Below is an example. `pattern:` is the name of the first parameter of `MapGet` and was not there until he typed the semi-colon. I have looked all over VS settings and can not find anything about it.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a Resharper feature. It's not inserting it in code, it's a hint to help you while reading the code

Comment: If this is what I think you mean, this is language specific for Basic & C#.  it can be found here: Options > Text Editor > C# (or Basic) > Advanced.  Look at the bottom of the page for "Inline Hints (experimental)"  There are a couple of choices.  Applies to VS 2019 at least.

Comment: I am still interested in how we can automatically insert parameter name labels into the source code. Not just a hint or ReSharper feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Environment :

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit)
Version 17.0.4

### Related [Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2019-v16-8-preview-2/)

### Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Advanced->Display inline parameter name hints

[image]

### Just check these.

#### c#：

[image]

#### Asp.net.core:

[image]

Comment: That was it, thank you!